# Use ajax like load

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, fancybox, live

I make some script, that have modal window on fancybox and on load it's fills by some content from other files. And i have some quetions:

I want to load content via ajax to my container (**#dialog-analogy**). But not full page - only one div with id (**#get-cats**). I dont know, how to get a content of id from ajax page. Thi is draft script:

```
function FillCats(catid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "catalogue.php?cat="+catid+"&size=1",
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                    var getcat = $('#get-cats').html(html); // wrong
            $("#dialog-analogy").html(getcat);
            }  
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't use live, it's bad, mkey? Use delegate!

Comment: Please ask **one** question at a time. Take your second question out of this one and post it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be glad to know that jQuery's [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function has exactly the functionality you want. You just append a selector to the end of the URL.

```
function FillCats(catid) {
    $("#dialog-analogy").load("catalogue.php?cat="+catid+"&size=1 #get-cats");
}
```

See the [*Loading Page Fragments* section](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) of the `load` documentation.

[Live example using `load`](http://jsbin.com/ebiger/)

---

If for some reason you can't use `load`, you can emulate it easily by building up the structure of what you've received via `$()` and then extracting the element(s) you want:

```
function FillCats(catid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "catalogue.php?cat="+catid+"&size=1",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#dialog-analogy").html($(data).find("#get-cats"));
        }
    });
}
```

[Live example emulating `load` using `ajax`](http://jsbin.com/ebiger/2)

Comment: @Vladimir: Your JavaScript code shouldn't be controlling cacheability. That's a job for the server. If the content needs to be non-cacheable, set the correct cache headers on the content server-side. But I've added an example using `ajax` instead.